# Is there any problem about create different Database contexts every time without using

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, database-connection, idisposable

Well, I would like to know what is the possible problems about use the following approach

```
CreateContextFactory().Create().QueryOpenConnectionCount();
```

instead of:

```
using (var context = CreateContextFactory().Create())
{
      openConnectionCount = context.QueryOpenConnectionCount();
}
return openConnectionCount;
```

and also if there is any problem about something like:

```
CreateContextFactory().Create().QueryOpenConnectionCount1();
CreateContextFactory().Create().QueryOpenConnectionCount2();
CreateContextFactory().Create().QueryOpenConnectionCount3();
```

This is because I have some methods in a class that are open db contexts as above, I could create a using statement for them, but so I would need to pass the context for all methods, and I would also need to refactor a helper that executes a transaction using a db context (because it creates its own context internally). So what are the problems about let the code stay this way?

Comment: Yes there is a problem, please research the disposable pattern, and why its used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, a data-context "owns" a connection, to avoid constantly having to fetch one from the pool and initialize it. Disposing the data-context typically disposes that connection.

So: if you keep creating data-contexts *without* properly disposing them, you're hemorrhaging connections, at least until GC steps in and undoes the mess (releasing the *unmanaged* part of the connection back into the unmanaged pool, if there *is* an unmanaged part).

This is a *bad thing*, and severely limits scalability and increases the number of open connections to your database server. So yes, you should dispose your data-contexts. Extending that to the general case: you dispose *any* `IDisposable` thing that *you're responsible for*, when you're done with it. With perhaps a few exceptions (`HttpClient`, `DataTable`, etc).

Note that C# 8 has a slightly terser (I would say "nicer", but that is subjective; I like it a lot) syntax for this, if your `using` statement reaches to the end of the current scope (i.e. to the next `}`):

```cs
using var context = CreateContextFactory().Create();
return context.QueryOpenConnectionCount();
```

or even with earlier C# you can make it simpler and remove the local:

```cs
using (var context = CreateContextFactory().Create())
{
    return context.QueryOpenConnectionCount();
}
```